# How to iterate over findPublisher and get list of names from the mongo reactive collection?

Tags: mongodb, reactive-programming, spring-reactive

## I have collection called "Person",after applying reactive find() on this collection ,it return the FindPublisher. How to iterate over this collections and get a list of a names .Here name is "column name".
Person collection structure :

{
"name":"John",
"age": 18
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you have a POJO for Person collection

```
Flux.from(db.getCollection("Person").find(Person.class)).map(Person::getName)
```

This will give you a flux of String with all names.